# Chef - Best way to copy file from a remote host

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to copy a file from a remote server to the chef client. I tried to use `remote_file` resource with ftp source but it requires ftp server to be installed on the chef client. Is there any way to copy a file from remote server to chef-client without explicitly installing anything on the client? I followed `https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html`

Comment: Where is the file being stored?

Comment: Its on a virtual machine. The chef client is trying to pull the file from a remote server . File location `/tmp/test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to put the file on a web server (or conversely run a simple web server where the file already is) and then use the `remote_file` resource.